# Why in Chrome do my prerendered pages flash?

Tags: html, google-chrome, preloading

I'm trying to create a gallery site that preloads the next page. I'm using link prerender and preload, which works well in Firefox and Chrome, but in Chrome the page flashes white momentarily when you go to it.

To see what I mean go to http://www.robertslowleyphotography.com/ebi-javascript-course/gallery/day%203/DSC_0954.jpg wait a few seconds so the next page is preloaded, then press right arrow key.

This doesn't happen in Firefox, so I guess I'm doing something wrong in Chrome? Perhaps I need to move some of my script tags around?

I'm using Chrome version 33.0.1750.117 on OS X 10.9.

Comment: It doesn't look as if it's "prerender'ing". If you check the network traffic in Chrome the request for those pages states "(cancelled)"!? And since the `img` element does not have any dimensions assigned, the page is "jumping" as you navigate to the next page (which I assume is your "page flash"). Hitting the back button is much quicker, which should (in theory) be how it is if the page is "preloaded".

Comment: Also, 'back button' is of no use here, the point is to ensure that when the user goes to the /next/ image/page they don't have to wait for the image/page resources to download.

It is much faster since I've done this than it was, but there is a 'flash' of white when you go to the new page in Chrome, which didn't happen without prerendering (although the loading was overall a lot slower), and this doesn't happen in Firefox.

Comment: (Admittedly I don't know much about "prerender" in Chrome...) But if pre-rendering is disabled when developer tools is opened then why is the behaviour exactly the same when developer tools is closed? My reference to the "back button" was related to the query that if a page is "prerendered/prefetched/preloaded" then why isn't it as quick as the back button?

Comment: If I hit the right arrow key (after waiting) I can see on my network traffic (not Chrome) that the image is being fetched (a big spike in my network traffic), but if I hit the left arrow key to go back to a page I have already been on I don't (it is pulled direct from cache - which to be honest, is what I would have expected if a page had been "prerendered") Incidentally I see the same spike in network traffic using Firefox as well, but it appears to handle the rendering a bit better. "The problem" seems to be in fetching the linked resources (ie. the image) of the "prerendered" page??

Comment: The behaviour is NOT the same. With Developer Tools closed the page is prerendered, so there is a very short white flash and then immediately the page is there. With Developer Tools open there is no flash and it takes longer for the page to load.

Trust me, you're barking up the wrong tree here. My question is why there is a flash of white when prerendered pages are displayed in Chrome. I appreciate your attempt to help, but you're not helping here.